# Multiple conditions for an if statement? (code doesn't work)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is for a jigsaw-like puzzle game. I want it so it goes directly to the next scene after all the pieces are in place. So beside each "map piece" is the coordinate where it will be in its proper place.

BUT //surprise surprise// it doesn't work :c is it even possible to put so many conditions in the first place?

Thank you for reading c: (justABeginner)

```
if (map1.x== 259.45 && 
map1.y== 77.05 &&

map2.x== 368.3 &&
map2.y== 69.45 && 

map3.x== 445.30 &&
map3.y== 90.4 &&

map4.x== 288.5 &&
map4.y== 207.15 &&

map5.x== 325.75 &&
map5.y== 164.65 &&

map6.x== 436.20 &&
map6.y== 187.65)

{
gotoAndStop (1, "Scene 3");
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can put as many conditions in as you like. But as akmozo said, this condition is very...specific. What happens when map1 has a x value of 259.44? Exactly, nothing.

Comment: Technically, your `if` is fine, but you have use many very precise values, so I'm not sure that you will get it working ! Instead, you can try to use [`hitTestObject()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29) and / or [`hitArea()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#hitArea).

Comment: You can also create a method that verifies all this conditions (or more if you need) and returns true or false. So, your if statement will be clean and easy to read. Something like: if (verifyMapPositions()) { gotoAndStop (1, "Scene3"); }. So, in this function, you can add and comment what be necessary and easily understand what is causing the return of 'false' and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me. If the condition doesn't evaluate to true, then it might actually be the values which are different. How about a simple debugging step before the If statement like printf to check if the values are exactly the same.

Sometimes, the precision will play a large role in such If statements.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Good advice, but AS3/Flash doesn't use `printf`. it uses a function called `trace(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find its not working because its particularly difficult to align an object with sub pixel accuracy. Because of this, you may want to consider "flooring" or "rounding" your numbers. I would suggest flooring to avoid it being rounded up to the next value.

```
if (Math.floor(map1.x) == 259 && Math.floor(map1.y) == 77 &&
    Math.floor(map2.x) == 368 && Math.floor(map2.y) == 69 && 
    Math.floor(map3.x) == 445 && Math.floor(map3.y) == 90 &&
    Math.floor(map4.x) == 288 && Math.floor(map4.y) == 207 &&
    Math.floor(map5.x) == 325 && Math.floor(map5.y) == 164 &&
    Math.floor(map6.x) == 436 && Math.floor(map6.y) == 187)
{
    gotoAndStop (1, "Scene 3");
}
```

Doing something like this will give you a more "fuzzy" comparison and should be easier to line up the puzzle pieces. Also, you may want to consider perhaps helping the user by adding a "snap to place" feature ...

```
function inrange(targetX, targetY, mapX, mapY, strength) {
    targetX -= (strength / 2);
    targetY -= (strength / 2);
    return (mapX >= targetX && mapX <= (targetX+strength) &&
        mapY >= targetY && mapY <= (targetY+strength));
}

//snap map piece into place if within 3 pixels
if (inrange(259, 77, map1.x, map1.y, 3)) {
  map1.x = 259;
  map1.y = 77;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general piece of advice, you should never use an equality check (==) with a floating point number. At some point you will find that you can't trust that 0.5 + 0.2 would equal 0.7. it may end up equalling 0.70000000001 or 0.6999999999999

As others have mentioned, try rounding your numbers, or better yet, try a small range, within which the piece is snapped into position, say plus or minus 10 pixels either way?